# Vectorized solution for pandas nested iterrows

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, group-by, iteration

Given an example dataframe:

```py
example_df = pd.DataFrame({"app_id": [1,2,3,4,5,6] ,
              "payment_date":["2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-04-05", "2020-01-05","2020-01-04"],
              "user_id": [12,12,12,13,13,13], 
              "application_date":["2021-02-01", "2021-02-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-04-05", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-04"] , "flag": [1,0,0,1,0,1], "order_column": [1,2,3,4,5, 6]})
```

What should be done is:

- I will explain what I want to do with an example:
- Iterate through all rows
- If the flag column is equal to 1 do as stated below
- For the first row `flag` column is 1 and the `user_id` for the row is 12. Look at all instances with `user_id`= 12 and compare their `application_date` with the `payment_date` of the first row. We see that the second row has an `application_date` greater than the `payment_date` of the first row. Then the label of the first row is 1. Third row also belongs to `user_id`= 12 but its `application_date` is not greater than the payment_date of the first row. If there is one or more observation that has `application_date` greater than `payment_date` of the first row, overall label of the first row is 1. If there are no such observations the overall label is 0.

I wrote the code for this with iterrows, but I want a more compact vectorized solution since iterrows can be slow with larger datasets. Like

```py
example_df.groupby("something").filter(lambda row: row. ...)
```

My code is:

```py
labels_dict = {}
for idx, row in example_df.iterrows():
    if row.flag == 1:
        app_id = row.app_id
        user_id = row.user_id
        user_df = example_df[example_df.user_id == user_id]
        labelss = []
        for idx2, row2 in user_df.iterrows():
            if (row2.order_column != row.order_column) & (row.payment_date < row2.application_date):
                label = 1
                labelss.append(label)
            elif (row2.order_column != row.order_column) & (row.payment_date >= row2.application_date):
                label = 0
                labelss.append(label)
        labels_dict[app_id] = labelss

final_labels = {}
for key, value in labels_dict.items():
    if 1 in value:
        final_labels[key] = 1
    else:
        final_labels[key] = 0
```

`final_labels` is the expected output. Basically, I am asking for all rows with `flag`= 1 to be labelled as 1 or 0 given the criteria I explained.

Desired output :

```py
{1: 1, 4: 0, 6: 1}

Here keys are app_id and values are labels (either 0 or 1)
```

Comment: what's the desired outcome?

Comment: @enke the desired outcome is the final_labels dictionary provided in the code, added it in dictionary form as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first built a temp dataframe with the only rows having 1 in `flag` and merge it with the full dataframe on `user_id`.

Then I will add a new boolean column being true if application_date is greater than payment_date and if the original app_id is different from the on from temp (ie different rows)

Finally it will be enough to count the number of true values per app_id and give a 1 if the number is greater than 0.

Pandas code could be:

```
tmp = example_df.loc[example_df['flag'] == 1,
                     ['app_id', 'user_id', 'payment_date']]

tmp = tmp.merge(example_df.drop(columns = 'payment_date'), on='user_id')

tmp['k'] = ((tmp['app_id_x'] != tmp['app_id_y'])
            & (tmp['application_date'] > tmp['payment_date']))

d = (tmp.groupby('app_id_x')['k'].sum() != 0).astype('int').to_dict()
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
{1: 1, 4: 0, 6: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

(i) Convert all dates to datetime objects

(ii) `groupby` "user_id" and for each group find the first "payment_date" using `first` and transform it for the entire DataFrame. Then compare it with the "application_date"s using `lt` (less than).

(iii) `groupby` "user_id" again to find how many entries satisfy the condition and assign values depending on whether the sum is greater than 1 or not.

```
example_df['payment_date'] = pd.to_datetime(example_df['payment_date'])
example_df['application_date'] = pd.to_datetime(example_df['application_date'])
example_df['flag_cumsum'] = example_df['flag'].cumsum()
example_df['first_payment_date < application_date'] = (example_df
                                                       .groupby(['flag_cumsum','user_id'])['payment_date']
                                                       .transform('first')
                                                       .lt(example_df['application_date']))
out = (example_df.groupby('flag_cumsum').agg({'app_id':'first', 
                                              'first_payment_date < application_date':'sum'})
       .set_index('app_id')['first_payment_date < application_date']
       .gt(0).astype(int)
       .to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{1: 1, 4: 0}
```

Comment: where does it check for the flag column?

Comment: @ I am not looking for the first payment_date but with the ones where flag column = 1

Comment: flag is not related to user_id

Comment: no they both matter. If flag = 1 for the current row, then I find all rows with user_id that belongs to the current row. Then compare the dates. Also application_date is not always equal to payment_date. It was in the example dataframe but not for all cases in the actual dataframe

Comment: it does not work for another case I tried. I changed the example_dataset to a version where this code does not work. The code I am asking for should work in the same logic as my example code. I dont think cumsum of flag column is necessary

Comment: @gato why is {6:1} in the final outcome? payment date is not less than application date for that flag

Comment: because for app_id 6 belongs to user_id = 13. For user_id 13 there are 2 more instances where the application date is greater than the payment date of app_id = 6